# Populating rails database with external api request data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, http, activerecord

I'm trying to populate my database table with data from an api. I have three models involved and set up as shown below:

```
class Fixture < ActiveRecord::Base

 belongs_to :homeTeam, class_name: "Team", foreign_key: "homeTeam_id"
 belongs_to :awayTeam, class_name: "Team", foreign_key: "awayTeam_id"
 belongs_to :league
 validates :matchday, presence: true
 validate :opposing_teams_must_be_different

#validates :externalFixtureID, :date, :matchday, :awayTeam, :homeTeam ,   :goalsHomeTeam, :goalsAwayTeam, presence: true

 def teams   
   [homeTeam, awayTeam]
 end 

  def opposing_teams_must_be_different
     errors.add(:awayTeam, "must be different from Home team") if    awayTeam_id == homeTeam_id
  end  

 class Team < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :league
    has_many :fixtures
  end 

   class League < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :teams
    has_many :fixtures
  end
```

To populate the database and making sure I get fixtures for the the league and teams, I used the following code in the Fixture model:

```
    def self.query_fixtures
     uri = URI.parse("http://api.football-data.org")
     http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
     request = Net::HTTP::Get.new("/alpha/soccerseasons/354/fixtures")
     response = http.request(request)
     parsed_matches = JSON.parse(response.body)["fixtures"]
     parsed_matches.each do |key, val|

     @league = League.find(5)
     @teams = @league.teams.each do |t|
         if key["homeTeamName"] = t.name
          homeTeam_id = t.id
       elsif key["awayTeamName"] = t.name
          awayTeam_id = t.id
       end
        @fixture = @league.fixtures.create!(:gameDate => key["date"], :matchday => key["matchday"], :awayTeam_id => awayTeam_id,
                                           :homeTeam_id => homeTeam_id, :goalsHomeTeam => key["result"]["goalsHomeTeam"],
                                           :goalsAwayTeam => key["result"]["goalsAwayTeam"])
         end

      end

    end
```

However, when I run the code in the rails console, the database gets populated but the awayTeam_id remains blank/null. How can I make sure I get both the awayTeam_id and homeTeam_id populated? The names of the teams and what I'm getting from the api are the same. I'm setting up the awayTeam_id and homeTeam_id based on homeTeamName = team.name and awayTeamName = team.name (Please see loop in query_fixtures method) Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Don't take this personally, but I'm voting to close this question because although it was a well asked question, the solution is very particular to your problem and won't be widely applicable for others.

Answer (score 1):

`if key["homeTeamName"] = t.name` will always be `true` because you've used the assignment operator (`=`) instead of the boolean comparison operator (`==`), and so the `elsif` will never be attempted (but would also always be true for the same reason).

Answer (score 1):

You're using the wrong flow control logic to populate those fields, this part:

```
if key["homeTeamName"] = t.name
   homeTeam_id = t.id
elsif key["awayTeamName"] = t.name
   awayTeam_id = t.id
end
```

Is using the `=` assignment operator which will set the value of `t.name` to `key["homeTeamName"]` and be truthy if `t.name` is not `nil` or `false` meaning only `homeTeam_id = t.id` will ever run.

Beyond that, even if you changed the operator to the correct `==` equality operator, the `if...elsif` control flow will mean that only either `homeTeam_id` *or* `awayTeam_id` will get set, never both.

What does each `@league.teams` object look like? Is the `t.id` the `homeTeam_id` or the `awayTeam_id`? Is there a `t.away_team_id`? Add a `puts t.inspect` right inside your `@league.teams.each` block and post the result, and I'll update my answer with more specific help.

Comment: thanks for your answer. This is how it looks like just for one team but contains more:    <ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy [#<Team id: 2, name: "Manchester United FC", code: "MUFC", short_name: "ManU", squad_market_value: "425,000,000 €", logo: "manchester-united.png", league_id: 5, created_at: "2015-05-13 04:53:08", updated_at: "2015-05-13 04:56:50", etc...> so how do I assign values to homeTeam_id and awayTeam_id based on homeTeamName and awayTeamName from the API call? Please refer to my association. Thanks in advance